# Why is the question about group interview company-specific?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

This question is closed with the reason of being company-specific: [In group interview, do candidates who are asked more questions than others have higher chance to be admitted?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/78109/26826)

Why? If there is a post from a country I don't live in discussing about group interview, then I'm pretty sure that this is not a company-specific, or even country-specific, problem. Which information in the question makes it company-specific?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted. OP disagreed with a question getting closed, so asked for an explanation on meta, which fits well with the purpose of meta. Please refrain from downvoting simply because you don't agree with the OP.

Comment: @Ooker Minor point, but either "is" in the title could/should be removed -- to nearly the same meaning, in this context.

Comment: @jpaugh is this is better? :)

Comment: Sure is :-) PS: I like your bio. I'm sure you'll do well! Since you've started young, you'll have more time (to learn, to think, to do, to help) than many.

Comment: @jpaugh haha thanks. Reading your bio and I'm sure you are as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with [MaskedMan's answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3967/16983), but want to expand a little. The question is off-topic because it really boils down to asking "Who is most likely to get hired?" without knowing any real information. Any answer would be purely speculating at the motives of your interviewer and the skillsets and personalities of the other candidates. A better question would be to ask

> In a group interview, I noticed that some of the candidates are getting more questions about their work or life background than others. Why would an interviewer ask different questions to different candidates? Should I be worried about my chances if I'm not getting asked as many questions?

This is still borderline on-topic, since there's still a good deal of speculation involved, but rather than asking us to guess what your interviewer is thinking, you are asking us, generically, in what situations such questioning would be appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

Group interviews are not company specific, but whether the decision to select candidates depends on how long the candidate was interviewed depends on the specific company, the specific interviewer(s), or even the specific interview. A general answer that is useful to a larger audience cannot be given.

Comment: if so, any question asks about interviewing can be interpreted as depending on the specific company

Comment: Certain interview behaviours are pretty common across companies, at least within a specific industry and we're happy to talk about those. The behaviour in question here isn't common across companies, so it's off-topic.

Comment: If the answer applies only to a specific situation, then it will be off-topic, regardless of whether it involves interviewing or not.

Comment: @PhilipKendall how to define "common"? Many questions ask about very rare and specific situations, yet they are considered as quality questions.

Comment: @Ooker Can you post some examples of those?

Comment: [Previous company name is ISIS, how to list on CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77952/26826)

Comment: You make a good point. Why don't you update your question with that example (and maybe more) so that it gets better visibility?

Answer (score 4):

The reason given for close was bad, but I still would have voted to close it with "Unclear what you're asking" or too broad.

There is no way of knowing WHY a candidate would get more questions without knowing the specifics, plus it asks us to get into the mind of the interviewer.

I tended to be a tough interviewer, and sometimes I'd try to shake a person up by asking a bunch of questions.  In other cases, if I felt that the interviewee was too nervous and not able to get some things out, I'd ask leading questions to get them to open up a bit.

There is no way that this question could get good answers, IMO.

I do, however disagree with the close reasons.